# Unexpected Public IP used for egress from AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have 2 Kubernetes Services of type LoadBalancer running in AKS 1.15.9

```
$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep Load
istio-system   istio-egressgateway       LoadBalancer   10.0.177.123   51.A.XXXXX
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway      LoadBalancer   10.0.198.456   20.B.XXXXX
```

However, when I run a Pod to check egress IP it is using `51.C.XXXX`

```
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org
the AKS egress IP address is shown in the response is 51.C.XXXX
```

I would of expected AKS to use one of the LoadBalancer IPs from the K8s Services.

Answer (score 1):

There's different between the `ingress` IP and `egress` IP.

**Egress**, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress):

> Outbound traffic from an AKS cluster follows Azure Load Balancer
> conventions. Before the first Kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer
> is created, the agent nodes in an AKS cluster are not part of any
> Azure Load Balancer pool. In this configuration, the nodes have no
> instance level Public IP address. Azure translates the outbound flow
> to a public source IP address that is not configurable or
> deterministic.

With that been said, The IP returns from `curl -s checkip.dyndns.org` is the egress IP. This is the outbound public IP of the aks cluster.

**Ingress**, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic):

> An ingress controller is a piece of software that provides reverse
> proxy, configurable traffic routing, and TLS termination for
> Kubernetes services. Kubernetes ingress resources are used to
> configure the ingress rules and routes for individual Kubernetes
> services. Using an ingress controller and ingress rules, a single IP
> address can be used to route traffic to multiple services in a
> Kubernetes cluster.

The ingress IP - in your case, the Load Balancer is the public\internal IP which responsible for reverse proxy and configurable traffic routing.

**Diagram:**

[image]

Comment: Isn't Egress IP (i.e. external public IP of outbound traffic from POD) the IP of first service of type LoadBalancer? So shouldn't it be 51.A or 20.B whichevers first?

Comment: From the link, I posted: `By default, the egress IP address from an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster is randomly assigned.`